# Floating Point Exception after installing rstan/brms

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I am currently trying to get rstan and brms running on my Fedora34 machine, and failing to do so since a couple of hours. Crucially, testing the example models or others always gives me a "Floating Point Exception". When I run the code in RStudio, it simply crashes and aborts everything, while running from the terminal does basically the same but gives me the hint of the floating point exception, as can be seen below. The error message is sadly limited to the info of "Floating Point exception".

The `make` command is:

```
  make -f '/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf' -f '/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk' \
  -f '/root/.R/Makevars' CXX='$(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)' \
   CXXFLAGS='$(CXX14FLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX14PICFLAGS)' \
SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX14LD)' \
SHLIB='filef8256c0e3305.so' OBJECTS='filef8256c0e3305.o'
```

make would use:

```
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library \
/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/RcppEigen/include/" \
 -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  \
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/BH/include" \
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/StanHeaders/include/src/" \
 -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/StanHeaders/include/"  \
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/library/rstan/include" \
-DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  \
-DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  \
-include '/usr/local/lib/R/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp' \
 -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  \
-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC \
-c filef8256c0e3305.cpp -o filef8256c0e3305.o
if test  "zfilef8256c0e3305.o" != "z"; then \
  echo g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L"/usr/lib64/R/lib" -Wl,-z,relro \
-Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld  \
-o filef8256c0e3305.so filef8256c0e3305.o  '/usr/local/lib/R/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a' \
-L'/usr/local/lib/R/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders \
-L'/usr/local/lib/R/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb  \
-L"/usr/lib64/R/lib" -lR; \
  g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L"/usr/lib64/R/lib" -Wl,-z,relro \
-Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld  -o filef8256c0e3305.so filef8256c0e3305.o \
 '/usr/local/lib/R/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a' \
 -L'/usr/local/lib/R/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders \
-L'/usr/local/lib/R/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb  \
-L"/usr/lib64/R/lib" -lR; \
fi
Floating point exception
```

This seems weird to me, as there should be no such errors because I am not trying to do anything fancy, just running the sample models. I tried reinstalling R completely, reinstalling rstan from source, but none of it worked. Also, cmdstanr gives me the info that all my c++ chains and paths are set correctly. The MCMC of cmdstanr also run correctly, so the problem seems to be specifically with brms and rstan.

Some package information:
OS: x86_64 (Fedora 34), linux-gnu; rstan: 2.21.2; Rcpp: 1.0.6; inline: 0.3.17, R 4.0.4

Comment: Given that Fedora 34 [looks like a brand new release](https://fedoramagazine.org/whats-new-fedora-34-workstation/), I wonder whether you've uncovered a new bug/inconsistency? If you don't get help here it may be worth posting on the Stan forums ...

Comment: Well, the main problem is that there is no error message apart from the mentioned "Floating Point Exception" . You're totally right about the exasperation though, sorry. I edited the post accordingly and added more information.

Comment: What do you get if you use `brms(..., backend="cmdstanr")` ... ??

Comment: I didn't knew about the possibility to change backends, but that works perfectly and smoothly. So this seems to pin down the problem to rstan? Using cmdstanr will be a great workaround for now, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that worked. I don't follow Stan that closely, but anecdotally there are lots of suggestions that stuff about `rstan` isn't working so well and the recommendation is "use `cmdstanr` instead" e.g. https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what the actual problem is, but given that `cmdstanr` works, you can work around it your problem via

```r
brms(..., backend="cmdstanr")
```

See [here](https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/reference/cmdstanr-package.html) for a little bit of discussion of the differences between `rstan` and `cmdstanr`: among them

> Running Stan via external processes results in fewer unexpected crashes, especially in RStudio.